# Understanding Asyncronous request processing in web frameworks

Tags: java, spring, asynchronous, jersey, playframework-2.3

How is asynchronous request processing in web frameworks like play! ,jersey ,spring different from the typical multi-threaded servers with pooled threads.
https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/async.html
https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/JavaAsync

One thread is listening and heavy processing happens in new thread
Also non blocking requests in web can not be compared to non blocking IO in java using selectors where one thread can read multiple channels.

From a server side perspective what does non-blocking mean.A multi threaded server is already non-blocking.Is this wrong?

What are the real benefits/use-cases of asynchronous web frameworks over multi threaded servers(**with thread pooling**)?
One might be ability to keep the HTTP request(s) alive in some way(How?)

Comment: if you are interested, you could also take a look at my project.

Answer (score 0):

Traditionally, each connection requires a thread. Since HTTP connections can be long-lived, this approach cannot sustain *too many*  concurrent users. At least that's what they say. But in practice, this does not seems to be a huge problem for java servers; you can always throw in more machines:)

With non-blocking, one thread can be used to server many connections; 10,000 shouldn't be a problem. So this approach might be more resilient for some applications. The catch is, programming in non-blocking is a little more difficult.